# Problem in reading from emulator storage on android studio

Tags: android

i write this in menifest for getting premission

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"

uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY"

and i uploaded 5 music files into storge with the Device File Explorer
i uploaded image that you will understand what i tryed to do.
but i tryed alot of codes.i cant even read the storge list with this:
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();`

my code in the image worked a week ago

i tryed for a days to fix i dont have any idea what is it.
this is a premission problem ?
or maybe my emulator is not good?

please suggests what can i do or try

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHHe7.png)

Comment: Don't post code as picture, paste the code in your question and format it (markdown).

Comment: Did you implement run time permission.. ?, Looks like you didn't implement it..

Comment: how i implement it?

Comment: Thanks i solved it with run time permission !!
i dont know how to close the question.